# Biblatex and "Already encountered file ______.aux"

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, include

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
  @misc{A01,
    author={Author, A.},
    year={2001},
    title={Alpha}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{mytext.tex}
  Hey, I want to repeat some text!
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\include{mytext}
\cite{A01}
\include{mytext}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Bibtex will complain because we're asking it to process the file `mytext.aux` twice:

> A level-1 auxiliary file: mytext.aux
>   Already encountered file mytext.aux
>   ---line 10 of file bi.aux
>   : \@input{mytext.aux  :
>                     }
>   I'm skipping whatever remains of this command

Is there any way to deal with that situation in a more clever way? What if I want to include the same snippet twice, but don't want this error to be reported, what should I do?

Comment: Use `\input` instead of `\include` so it does not create an auxiliary file?

Comment: Yes, but what if I still want to benefit from the `\include` features? (Like `\includeonly`, for instance, cf. [http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/34551](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/34551)). (PS: thanks for the edit.)

Comment: I don't see why you would want to use \include in such a situation. What do you gain from \includeonly for *snippets*?  Also I would never use \include in an article.

Comment: As so often this works just fine with `backend=biber`. You should switch backends anyway since BibTeX is only supported as legacy backend.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : `article` was just for the example, I actually use this code for a `beamer` document (and the included document is a customized table of contents). And, indeed, `biber` handles that situation just fine. So I guess your answer would be "either don't use `include` that way, or switch to `biber`?

Answer (score 1):

Use Biber instead of BibTeX. Biber uses one single `.bcf` file for the entire document and voids the `.aux` files.

Since BibTeX is only considered a legacy backend for existing documents that cannot switch to Biber and only supports a limited set of features, a switch to Biber is recommended anyway.